# Is there a way to use a TypeScript file in place of ormconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I do want to export my ormConfig from a TypeScript file located by the path ***src/config/ormconfig.ts*** with the following content

```
export const ormConfig = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'admin',
  password: '123456',
  database: 'hello-world',
}
```

So I could import it from the file ***src/database/index.ts*** using the following strategy:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { ormConfig } from "../config/ormconfig";

const dataSource: DataSource = new DataSource(ormConfig);
```

The problem is that TypeScript throws an error saying arguments are missing:
***"[...] is missing the following properties from type 'AuroraMysqlConnectionOptions': region, secretArn, resourceArnts"***

Has someone have a workaround for this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the type of your `ormConfig`

```
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from "typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions";

const ormConfig: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
```